# Solving simultaneous logarithmic equations from Newton's law of Cooling

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, systems-of-equations, physics

> A cup of warm water at $46$ degrees is placed into a refrigerator. 10 minutes later, the water is $39$ degrees, and another 10 minutes later, the water is $33$ degrees.
>   Use Newton's law of cooling to find the ambient temperature in the refrigerator.

Newton's law of cooling is $\frac{dH}{dt}=-k(H-H_a)$ where $H$ is the temperature of an object and $H_a$ is the ambient temperature. This condenses into $y=y_0e^{-kt}$, where $y$ is $H-H_a$ and $y_0$ is $y$ when $t=0$.

If $t$ is diven in units of 10 minutes, we get $y_0-7=y_0e^{-k}$ and $y_0-13=y_0e^{-2k}$, which can be converted to 
$$\ln (y_0-7)-\ln y_0=-k$$
$$\ln (y_0-13)-\ln y_0=-2k$$
But I can't get any further.

Wolfram says $y_0$ is $49$ degrees, which means the refrigerator is $-3$ degrees.
How do I get this result?

Comment: Probably, the difficulty was that you had one repeated typo in your equations with the $\ln$. I added a solution where we don't need to use $\ln$ to get $H_a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, as you said, the solution of the heat equation is:
$$y(t)=y_0e^{-kt}$$
with
$y_0$ and $k$ unknown and
$y(1) = y_0 - 7$, and
$y(2) = y_0 - 13$.

Hence
$$
y_0 - 7 = y_0 e^{-k} \\
y_0 - 13 = y_0 e^{-2k}
$$

Let $w = e^{-k}$, thus, $w^2 = e^{-2k}$.
With this substitution, the equations become
$$
y_0 - 7 = y_0 w \\
y_0 - 13 = y_0 w^2
$$

Solving the first equation for $w$ and plugging the solution into the second we get:
$$
\frac{y_0 - 7}{y_0} = w \\
y_0 - 13 = y_0 \left( \frac{y_0 - 7}{y_0} \right) ^2
$$

To solve the second equation for $y_0$ we can multiply both sides by $y_0$ and we get:
$$
y_0^2 - 13 y_0 =  y_0^2 - 14 y_0 + 49
$$

I.e.: $ y_0 = 49 $ which makes

$$
H_a = 46 - 49 = -3
$$
(the final solution should have units).

Just for fun, we get that $w = \frac{49 - 7}{49} = \frac{6}{7}$ 
and $k = -\ln w = 0.15\ldots$.

---

Remark: I only applied the logarithm in the end because we aimed to find $y_0$ to get $H_a$. We do not need to compute $w$ nor $k$ to solve this problem.